# PostgreSQL why table bloat ratio is higher than autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor

Tags: postgresql, performance

I found that bloat ratio of feedback_entity is 48%

```
current_database | schemaname |       tblname         |  real_size  | extra_size |   extra_ratio    | fillfactor | bloat_size |   bloat_ratio    | is_na 
 stackdb         | public     | feedback_entity       |  5743878144 | 2785599488 | 48.4968416488746 |        100 | 2785599488 | 48.4968416488746 | f
```

but when I check autovacuum setting it has autovaccum setting of 10%

```
stackdb=> show autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor;
 autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor 
--------------------------------
 0.1
(1 row)

stackdb=> show autovacuum_vacuum_threshold;
 autovacuum_vacuum_threshold 
-----------------------------
 50
(1 row)
```

Also:
Autovacuum setting is on.
Autovacuum for mentioned table are running regularly at defined threshold

My Question is when auto vacuum is running at 10% of dead tuples why would bloat size increase to 48%. I have seen similar behaviour in hundreds of databases/tables. Why table bloat is always increasing and doesn't come down after every vacuum.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe : Would you please assist here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you used to calculate the table bloat is unreliable. To determine the actual bloat, use the `pgstattuple` extension and query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('public.feedback_entity');
```

But the table may really be bloated. There are two major reasons for that:

1. autovacuum runs and finishes in a reasonable time, but it cannot clean up the dead tuples. That may be because there is a long-running open transaction, an abandoned replication slot or a prepared transaction. See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/) for details.
2. autovacuum runs too slow, so that dead rows are generated faster than it can clean them up. The symptoms are lots of dead tuples in `pg_stat_user_tables` and autovacuum processes that keep running forever. The straightforward solution is to use `ALTER TABLE` to increase `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` or reduce `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` for the afflicted table. An alternative approach, if possible, is to use [HOT updates](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/).